# String with special char sorting issue in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to sort a string containing - and /. But I can't understand the output

```
Console.WriteLine(@"a-b".CompareTo(@"a/b"));
Console.WriteLine(@"-b".CompareTo(@"/b"));
Console.WriteLine(@"a-".CompareTo(@"a/"));
Console.WriteLine(@"-".CompareTo(@"/"));
Console.WriteLine(@"-/".CompareTo(@"/-"));
Console.WriteLine(@"--".CompareTo(@"//"));
```

The output is

```
1
1
-1
-1
1
-1
```

While I expect all output should be 1. Did I misunderstand sth going on here? Thanks

Comment: `@"-".CompareTo(@"/") == -1` which means that `-` occurs before `/` in lexical order

Comment: That's when you [read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: the question is about why "a-b".CompareTo(@"a/b") returns 1 while @"a-".CompareTo(@"a/") returns -1

Comment: Then update the question to make the point clearer ;)

Comment: .NET uses the same kind of sorting rules that everybody uses when they lookup a word in a dictionary or telephone book.  Just lookup "long-winded" for example.  Use the Compare() overload that takes a StringComparison to change, "ordinal" is the programmer's way.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Character sets include **ignorable characters**. The `CompareTo(String)`
>   method does not consider such characters when it performs a
>   culture-sensitive comparison. For example, **if the following code is
>   run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a comparison of "animal" with
>   "ani-mal"** (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two
>   **strings are equivalent**.

That means `-` is ignored if you compare in a culture-sensitive manner.

This will give your expected result(all negative):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal(@"a-b", @"a/b"));
Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal(@"-b",@"/b"));
Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal(@"a-",@"a/"));
Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal(@"-",@"/"));
Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal(@"-/",@"/-"));
Console.WriteLine(String.CompareOrdinal(@"--",@"//"));
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the hyphen on the keyboard and `\u00AD` are not the same. For example, the following returns 1: `@"\u00AD".CompareTo(@"-")`